# What does extendable array do when we re-allocate the memory for array when it's full?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, amortized-analysis

I'm just encountered with this question that if we have a dynamically allocated array, it takes O(1) to do the insertion. But when the array is full, we need to re-allocate double space to the array, so copying of the old array takes O(n).

Is there any way we can make it O(1)?

I have read some articles saying about the extendable array but I don't quiet understand it. Can anyone help explain it more?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Why you don't use a **list** then ???

Comment: @NeerajJain because list would take O(n) to insert at the end of list.

Comment: @Zip No it doesn't. `LinkedList` takes O(1) (although it's not very fast otherwise). `ArrayList` is almost always the best choice for a simple non-concurrent list (without head removals).

Comment: @Kayaman Thanks for that. Do you know anything about extendable array? I just heard it we can use that so I'm curious that what we would do with extendable array.

Comment: @Zip `ArrayList` is an extendable array. There's very little reason not to use it.

Comment: @Zip and why does you think so that list is O(n) !! [Check this out](http://www.javaexperience.com/time-complexity-of-collection-classes/)

Comment: @NeerajJain Sorry I thought you said list is the linked list. I used C more before so I misunderstand it.

Comment: Note that although ArrayList is O(N) when it needs to expand, that happens increasingly rarely due to the doubling - so it's amortized O(1).

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for comment. I'm still have question that after it resizes, what do I need to do with the old data? The question says NO copying from old array.

Comment: @Zip: What question do you mean? `ArrayList` *does* copy the contents. It's unclear what you're looking for here, to be honest...

Comment: The question is: is there a list that reallocates storage as required rather than dumping the old list and recreating it? LinkedList does that, but it is not very efficient.

Comment: You've already been told that LinkedList is *O(1)* when inserting at the end. Unclear what you're asking now.

Answer (score 4):

Allocating double the space each time forms a geometric progression.  This means that while some insertions (those that trigger the expansion) are very expensive, they are so infrequent that the amortized performance is still O(1).  For example, inserting a billion elements only requires 30 doublings (2^30=1,073,741,824).